# How would one go about writing the momentum equilibrium for a rocket whose thrust is equal to the force of gravity? (The rocket's "hanging" in the sky

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science, propulsion

My question specifically is where do we look for the "missing" momentum. If I understand the situation correctly we have some momentum from the exhaust of the rocket. Where do we get the "missing" momentum if the rocket is not moving, but the net momentum should be equal to zero?

Answer (score 0):

The Earth and rocket pull on each other with equal and opposite force hence equal and opposite momentum, conserving net momentum.

The rocket and exhaust push on each other with equal and opposite force hence equal and opposite momentum, conserving net momentum.

For the hanging rocket, the "missing" momentum has gone to the Earth, which a human has difficulty noticing because the Earth is so massive.